# Show timestamp or age on global inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, global-inbox

Can we see the timestamp or age of an entry in the StackExchange header inbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inbox is pretty info dense already, so I've made the tooltip for each event a timestamp of the "XXX ago" form.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have those inbox entries that were cause of 'small red number' marking number of new responses with e.g. red dot, or red type ('comment', 'answer', etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to see the full timestamps of each inbox entry? I'd really like to have this feature, even if that means that the inbox windows increases in its width. May this be achievable over a usersetting?