# The StackExchange top popup shows "2 Inbox" while nothing pending

Tags: support, status-completed, global-inbox

While visiting the various sites, the top   <sup>Stack**Exchange**</sup>   shows *2 inbox* while nothing is pending nowhere.
Did refresh a lot...

How can I fix that or find out where some messages are waiting?

Comment: Poss dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65637/duplicate-entries-in-inbox

Comment: @thyrgle: Don't think so.

Comment: Are you **absolutely certain** there was nothing pending anywhere? See the thread that KennyTM linked below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [T.J. Crowder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134069/t-j-crowder) surmised, the problem is that the items in the inbox are being sorted by their "tooltip timestamp" instead of their actual timestamp.

This is a side effect of [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65576/show-timestamp-or-age-on-global-inbox), it just so happened that the events I tested with were in order by both relative and absolute timestamps (at the time I tested).  My bad.

This has been fixed in the repo, and will go out sometime today.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happening to me and it **drives me nuts**. It lights up red showing (1) or (2) or whatever, but then when I click it and go to the Inbox, all I see is the same stuff that's been there. Perhaps it's an issue with the sort order? The top item for me has been a comment on an SU post of mine that dates from yesterday sometime; definitely not the most recent comment I've had.

It's a good idea (a **very** good idea), but there appear to be some gremlins...

**Update**: It's a sort order problem (or at least, there is a sort order problem; I don't know that it's the only problem). It just lit up on me again, and so I walked through the list, and found that I had a comment from 20 seconds earlier appearing half-way down the list (below the fold) bracketed by comments from yesterday on either side. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65657/global-inbox-is-showing-the-comments-in-completely-wrong-order) that KennyTM linked to, the order's just all messed up.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65657/global-inbox-is-showing-the-comments-in-completely-wrong-order.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yup. I was just coming back to post that I'd found that there *were* new comments when it lit up, they were just buried in the middle of the list.

Comment: I followed that link and checked at the bottom of the list, there was *one* comment waiting, while the window said `7!` (not 5,040). That window should simply change the color / clearly show which comments are new... if she is *that* sure of that number :-)

Comment: *"...and checked the bottom of the list..."* That's my point. The new things are **not** necessarily at the bottom. Or at the top. The distribution seems random (for me, new ones mostly appear in the middle), although I suspect it's not random, it's just based on something non-obvious (and clearly not intentional).