# Global-inbox is showing the comments in completely wrong order

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

As shown, the most recent comment is found at the bottom.

[image]

Not only that, the comments in my inbox from top to bottom have the timestamps (currently)

1. yesterday
2. yesterday
3. 9 hours ago
4. 9 hours ago
5. 9 hours ago
6. 5 mins ago
7. 20 mins ago
8. 2 hours ago
9. 19 hours ago
10. 16 hours ago
11. 16 hours ago
12. 13 hours ago
13. 13 hours ago
14. 13 hours ago
15. 12 hours ago
16. 12 hours ago

It seems like it is `ORDER BY CAST(timestamp AS STRING) DESC`.

Comment: I'd already flagged this internally, but: I'm glad it wasn't just my imagination ;p

Comment: Apparently right now it's listing newest comments at the bottom.

Comment: @Jeff: Not necessarily. Your recent comment which I found 40 seconds after is shown at the 2nd place because `40 seconds` is the largest string before `yesterday`. http://i.imgur.com/lalZd.png

Comment: Ah, that was just an artifact of a comment being made 1 minute ago at the time.  I saw your comment to me third from the bottom.  A couple minutes later, it moved up.  :)

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, I have no idea what order they're actually in, but they're not in any obvious most-recent-first or least-recent-first. I have comments from 20 seconds ago bracketed by comments from yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-stackexchange-top-popup-shows-2-inbox-while-nothing-pending/65682#65682), the underlying bug was that inbox items were being sorted by their relative timestamps (as strings) rather than by their actual creation dates.

The last build has fixed this error.

Comment: Just letting you know I just experienced something similar (see [below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132501/181223)).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bump this because I just experienced the same problem.
A new comment was very far down the inbox list. At the same time, an older comment that I had read before was highlighted as if it was new.

Comment: So ping the dev in [his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65686/152859) so he gets a notification.

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65657/global-inbox-is-showing-the-comments-in-completely-wrong-order#comment366727_65686), thanks @ShaDowWizArd.