# Received new notification about an old comment

Tags: bug, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global-inbox is showing the comments in completely wrong order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65657/global-inbox-is-showing-the-comments-in-completely-wrong-order)

Just thought I should report this seeing it's still being developed and a WIP.

I received a comment notification in the global inbox from an old comment.  IIRC, the comment was posted exactly 24 hours ago from when I noticed it today.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784677/list-all-duplicates-in-list-object-including-quantity/3784733#3784733) (and associated comment)

---

**edit:**
<s>Upon further inspection, I just received a notification (in the SO inbox) about a legitimately new comment at about the time that I received the notification about the other in the global inbox.  This one didn't even appear in the global inbox.</s>

Now I'm thinking the notification was just linked to the wrong comment.
I'm beginning to think it's just in the wrong order and the newest notification is not appearing on top like I'm expecting (as noted in the linked bug report).  Turns out my newest message was at the bottom.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793111/how-do-i-know-the-type-of-object-and-cause-it/3793191#3793191) (and associated comment)

---

May be related to [Global-inbox is showing the comments in completely wrong order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65657/150562).

Comment: +1 I had something similar happen earlier as well.

Comment: Funny, I just received a notification right now.  Just found that previously reported new comment was at the bottom.  Though now I don't know which comment initiated the most recent notification.  There was nothing new this time around.  Oh, wait, it was @Martin's comment.  :)